# Get list of all expiring memberships, but excluding all those that have been "renewed" with another membership type

Tags: civimember, searchkit, custom-search

I need to send reminders to expiring memberships. But I would like to exclude all those that have been "renewed" with another membership type (bought another membership type that fundamentally continues the previous membership).

I have many membership types, there are no old or new membership types, but for example a member can renew for 1 year or 2 years for different types (free book, access to digital magazines...).
I have to send the reminder only to those who have not renewed any membership.

How can I do this? It would be preferable for me to use SearchKit. It would also be fine to do a custom where, but I don't know how to do it in a custom extension.

Answer (score 2):

You can create a smart group with all current membership.

Using searchkit you can build a list for all expired membership and not in above create group.

Hth

Pradeep

Comment: Thanks, I think it is a good solution, I hadn't thought of that. If I wanted to filter by group in Form Builder, I found olnly "In groups" and not "Not in groups". Is there a solution? Then please can you give me a reference (documentation) to create a custom filter with Form Builder, not based on a custom field, but on a set of conditions? This is to don't have to think and set filters every time and without creating "n" menus or forms.

Comment: Perhaps for complex filters it is better to create nested smart groups.